# toggleclass with background-image issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image, toggleclass

i have a div with an id that i want to use for switchin between 2 classes.
the purpose is to change class when i click showing a different background-image (inside, infact, in the second class).
the div comes with a class default

```
 <a href="#"><div id="equipment" class="flash"> </div></a>
```

this is the css

```
 #equipment {

float: right;
margin-right: 30px;
width: 55px;
height: 81px;

 }
   .flash {


background: url('equipment.jpg');
background-size: 55px 81px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }


.flashOn {



background: url ('equipment3.jpg')  no-repeat scroll;
background-size: 55px 81px;

font-size: 20px;


     }
```

and this is the simple jquery

```
 $('#equipment').click(function(){

 $('#equipment').toggleClass('flashOn');

 });
```

i tested and the toggleClass work partially. as the font size change.. but it doesnt change the background image in the div. Any clue? thanks in advance.,
Paolo

Comment: Are these classes in that same order as shown in your stylesheet? Your div will end up having both classes, and since their selector specificity is identical, the last one will “win”.

Comment: You could just do `$('#equipment').toggleClass('flashOn flash');`, as that would remove one class, and make all the issues go away

Comment: hi adeneo thanks. it change class but again, i dont see any image backgroundm the equipment2.jpg as you can see here. http://www.paolobergomi.it/sitob/index.html#

Comment: Remove the space in your CSS `background: url('equipment3.jpg') no-repeat scroll;`

Comment: great. that was the issue. i apologize..did not know that the space could be relevant. :) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$('#equipment').click(function(){

 $('#equipment').toggleClass('flashOn');

 });
```

to

```
    $('#equipment').click(function(){

 $('#equipment').toggleClass('flashOn flash');

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/osmanrahimi/xwnKP/215/